# Allow unregistered users to query Firestore to check if an E-Mail already exists

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Right now, in my Firestore rules only registered users have read / write access to my project. However, I also want to verify in my registration process if an E-Mail already exists, which means also anonymous user have access to my "users" data.

I am unsure how this is compliant from a security perspective. Should I create something like a "emails" collection and duplicate all E-Mail addresses here and allow anonymous users to query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that is indeed the typical approach. Duplicate the data that you want anonymously accessible into a separate collection, and grant broader access restrictions there.

In the rules for that collection of email addresses you will typically [use granular rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) that allow reading each specific document, but to disallow listing all documents. Something like:

```
match /emails/{email} {
  // Applies to single document read requests
  allow get: if <condition>;

  // Applies to queries and collection read requests
  allow list: if false;
}
```

This means that once the user has typed a specific email address, you can check if a document exists for that email address. But they can't just get all documents from the collection to scrape your user base.

Comment: Frank - thank you for your example. I am a bit lost about the <condition> for the single document read request. Should there be any condition when I want to allow literally everyone to do this single read request?

Comment: Oops... good one. In that case it should be `if true`. You could also consider: `if request.auth.uid != null`, and use anonymous sign-in. That doesn't quire your users to enter any data, but gives at least one extra level of protection.