# How can i validate password in firebase? (Not user credentials)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to have a db collection in **firebasereal time database**  which contains a *name* and a *password*.

```
node:
  |_ name1: password
  |_ name2: password
```

In other words, for example there is a room which is password protected, that someone wants to join. 
**One way to validate is requesting the password from the db** via the nameId, which then it  sends back to client and than on client side the validation happens. But **it does not seem like a good idea** to send the password to the client.

Is there a **server side validation**? Like sending the nameId and password to firebase and the authentication happens there?

An other question, how can i **hash the password with firebase?**
It is a second layer of validation after the user validation (singInWithEmailAndPassword is the 1st layer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a room to only be accessible if a user knows a certain "password", I typically embed that password in the name/id of the room. That way the user will have to know the name of the room in order to be able to read it.

You can then secure this with Firebase's server-side security rules by disallowing the user's from querying the collection of rooms. In other words, they can read an individual room if they know the name, but they can't get a list of all rooms.

For an example of such rules, see: [Allow unregistered users to query Firestore to check if an E-Mail already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766574/allow-unregistered-users-to-query-firestore-to-check-if-an-e-mail-already-exists/59772033#59772033),

Comment: For example, `name = "some name"`, `password = "1234"` then the id would be `id = "some name1234"`? 

What i thought to do is, send the name and password to firebase and a function validate if the db contains them.